# IDA Pro/IDA Python, producing file via terminal

Tags: ida, ida-plugin, idapython, idapro-sdk

I am using IDA Pro 6.5 and running it via terminal with the following command line switches:

1. -B (to run in batch mode, should automatically generate a .asm file containing results)
2. -S running a script in which the only functionality is to convert all of the binary into instruction.

When I ran in batch mode prior to the script, it would generate a .asm file that I would then be able to manipulate. However, now this file doesn’t appear. Is there a quick fix or any IDA Python methods I can include in order to create an output file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here it is. 
Run it with idal -c -A -S./script.py ./test.bin

```
# I didn't check this code, please use carefully !
# IDAPython documentation is at https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/

import idautils
import idc

for ea in idautils.Segments():
    segend = idc.GetSegmentAttr(ea, idc.SEGATTR_END)
    start = ea
    while start < segend:
        idc.MakeCode(start)
        start = idc.FindUnexplored(start+1, idc.SEARCH_DOWN)

idc.GenerateFile(idc.OFILE_ASM, idc.GetInputFile()+".asm", 0, idc.BADADDR, 0)

idc.Exit(0)
```

Comment: I just debugged the answer to your previous question :)

Comment: Thanks! Yes I was working on the GenerateFile function but wasn't quite sure how to get the full functionality.

Comment: I don't have `idal` anywhere inside "/Applications/IDA Pro 7.5", where is this script supposed to be located?

Comment: @ZachRiggle Actually any correct(32/64bitwise) ida executable should fit.

Comment: @ws It appears the issue is that the binary I wanted is `idat` not `idal`.  Thanks in any case!
After adjusting my $PATH, now I have: $ which idat == /Applications/IDA Pro 7.5/ida.app/Contents/MacOS/idat